# ... is done in agreement with xxx?

Tags: grammaticality, writing-style

**Background:**

I'm writing a professional (technical) report in which I want to express the following in one simple sentence: The whole report is written based on a certain assumption, except one part that's based on a different assumption. (Let's say a battery has 10 Volts in parts of the report, and 12 Volts in another part). This means that one part of the report is "wrong". I want to express that the way I'm doing this has been "approved" by our client. The part in parentheses is just to illustrate the context.

> (In most of the report 10V has been used. However, the voltage is actually 12V. 
>   12V has been used in chapter 2 only.)
>
> **The usage of a different voltage in chapter xxx only, *is done in
>   agreement with client name.***

However, the last part of that sentence doesn't seem good to me. I think it's grammatically correct, but not something a native English speaking person would write. Can I say / write: "*... is done in agreement with*"?

Comment: But "keeping the rest of the report unchanged" is different from "the usage of a different voltage".

Comment: @Andrew I guess this is a website where I should not change the context much when explaining stuff =P It's supposed to _look like_ it's written at the same time, not as bits and pieces. Therefore, even though one part of it is actually an update, I won't write that explicitly. But, I do have to explain why there is a difference. More to the point: "In most of the report 10V has been used. However, the voltage is _actually_ 12V. 12V has been used in chapter 2 only. The use of a different voltage is in agreement with xx." (This is not exactly what I've written but the meaning is about the same.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you currently have boils down to *The usage is done.* Usages generally aren't done, but they can be agreed upon.

> The usage of a different voltage in chapter *x* only has been agreed with the client.

I wouldn't use a comma to separate "The usage" from "has been agreed". You could also lose *only* as that can be inferred from the context.

The distinction between *usage* and *use* might be commented upon.

> **usage**
>   The way in which a word or phrase is normally and correctly used
>   Habitual or customary practice, especially as creating a right, obligation, or standard
>
> **use**
>   The action of using something or the state of being used for a purpose
>
> [Both ODO]

*Usage* is about the **way** something is used; *use* merely means that it has been used (this is evident in the title "English Language & Usage"). I would write the sentence as

> The use of a different voltage in chapter *x* has been agreed with the client.

Comment: Thanks Andrew =) To me, it feels like something is missing here: "The use [...] has been agreed with the client", but I guess that's  the reason why I asked this question in the first place. I can't really tell what's correct and what's not. =)

Comment: The point is that *done* does not go with the noun *use*: "I did this use," for example. Uses aren't "done". Using "The use has been agreed" is missing something which narrows down what you're talking about; normally one would say "The use of x has been agreed", but it could be "This use has been agreed." You could say "The usage has been agreed," because *usage* is more abstract than *use*, as I explain in the answer -- but *usage* isn't the right word here: you need *use,* which means you need *use of*.

Comment: As a native American speaker, "has been agreed with" sounds awkward to me. Maybe it is missing a preposition (agreed upon/agreed to)? I would reword the whole thing to "The client has agreed to the use of a different voltage in chapter X". Or "The client has agreed to the use of the incorrect voltage in all chapters except X".

Comment: @Andrea AmE seems to love its additional prepositions (eg *meet with*). BrE tends not to use them. If it's to be used in an AmE context, then some adjustment may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

"... in agreement with [client]" - works

"... after agreement from [client]" - same idea, but stronger focus on the need of this agreement.

"... after consulting with [client]" - less focus on need for agreement.

"... have been cleared with [client]" - also has focus on the need for input from client.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all native speakers but I'd write "*is done with the consent of xxx*".  *consent* or

Comment: This works for me, although I think "approval" may be better as it implies more positive agreement from the client. But both "consent" and "approval" imply that the change came from the OP and the client was just asked if it was acceptable. "Agreement" may be the best word, as it is more positive about the client's involvement. The bit I think is clumsy is the "is done with", I'd probably just put "The use of a different voltage in chapter xxx was agreed with xxx". (edited because Andrew Leach is right about "use" vs "usage")

Answer (score 0):

The usual word for the purpose in the OP's context is *concurrence,* an agreement in opinion.

*[concurrence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concurrence)*

> 1. Agreement in opinion.
> 2. Cooperation, as of agents, circumstances, or events.  
>      "Stuart and Clarke felt highly displeased at his taking so precipitate a step, without waiting for their concurrence, … "
>    ([Washington Irving, *Astoria or Anecdotes of an enterprise beyond the Rocky Mountains*](http://irving.thefreelibrary.com/Astoria-or-Anecdotes--of-an-enterprise-beyond-the-Rocky-Mountain/1-56#concurrence))

Whence,

> The usage of a different voltage in chapter xxx only, is done in **concurrence** with xxx.

Better still,

> The usage of a different voltage in chapter xxx only, is done **with the concurrence of** xxx.

As in

> But in court-annexed mediation and **in concurrence with** the parties, we add a rider that the compromise agreements are “not contrary to law… public policies and public order. 
> (Benedicto Q Sánchez on [Sunstar](http://www.sunstar.com.ph/bacolod/opinion/2014/05/26/sanchez-illegal-win-wins-344776),  May 26, 2014)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for

> With the *permission* of X, chapter Y...

Answer (score -1):

Consider also:

> The use of a different voltage in chapter 5, is in [accordance](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accordance) with xxx

The only is unneeded as there is only one chapter number given in context.

Comment: +1 for *use* rather than *usage*, though I think 'by agreement with the client' would better reflect what OP is trying to say.

Comment: @TimLymington I was angling for the use of accordance as 'in a manner conforming [with] (the wishes of)'. I agree that your phrasing is also robust.